# how to make all of Controller Load at Start Launch application (xcode)?

Tags: xcode, load, viewcontroller

The problem is, when I do something, such as input @"Hallo" with code to UITextField at different Controller that I havent opened, that UITextField is still null, but if I already opened it before, the UITextField will become "Hallo"

the program like this

```
+(void)MakeController2LblTextIsLikeMyStringAtController1{
         Controller2.lblText.text=MyString;
}
```

if I never loaded Controller2 before I call this method. Controller2.lblText.text is still null, but If I havent loaded Controller2, lblText.text will isEqual MyString.

the problem is, If I have 20-50 different Controller, how can I make all of it load at start launch application? How to force open a view controller to load programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Don't load all your view controllers at launch. The OS will kick you out due to memory usage quickly if you try. Instead, look at implementing the MVC paradigm properly. Your need to access an UILabel in another view controller suggest your app's structure is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but how do you think you can assign some text to a UITextField which does not even exist? When you alloc and init a controller (any class) its properties are also created (initialized), thus you can access them. You have to bear this in mind that there's no way to access to something or its properties that does not exist.
 And why you can acess them once you load ([alloc init]) the Controller2 is probably because you do not deallocate them. That's as simple as this.
 If you want to load all of them at startup you can have an array of all the Controller classes and let the foreach loop iterate through it and [alloc init] them one by one. But as I do not exacly know what your application is meant to do the suggested method might be irrelevant in your situation. That's just a way of doing what you want.

Comment: I totally agree with @Johan Kool in that loading that many controllers at launch is discouraged and you'll most probably run out of memory and the app will be forced to shut down by the OS. And I suspect you do really need to load them all at once. You should review your application structure and the code flow.